# JS and CSS files not loading inside html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My folder structure looks like,

```
MyProject
       |
       webcontent
```

Inside webContent folder I am having my html, js,CSS files.
Here I am loading the js & CSS files directly as below.

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
```

But I want to keep the js and CSS file in different folder and I need to call them where I want. But I am not getting where to place the js & CSS file and how to define the path inside html or jsp.

Comment: Well, what folder **do** you want them in? We can't help you with relative paths unless we know where we're going.

Comment: Inside webcontent I have folders like js,CSS,Images.

Comment: Good, I guessed right.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where they are and how you configure your web server. With a default configuration on nearly all web servers, if you want your scripts in a *subdirectory* of `webcontent`, then just add `directory-name/` in front of the paths. E.g., for:

```
MyProject/
       |
       webcontent/
               |
               js/
                  jquery-1.0.2.js
                  jquery-ui.js
               css/
                  jquery-ui.css
```

then

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
```

The search terms for this are "relative URL" and/or "relative path."

Comment: And store the html (or jsp,php,etc) files directly under webcontent

Comment: Sorry.. Now its working. But my image is not loaded.

Comment: .ui-state-hover .ui-icon,
.ui-state-focus .ui-icon {
 background-image: url("images/ui-icons_555555_256x240.png");
}    Code in CSS file. I need to load the image which resides inside webContent/images/ui-icons_555555_256x240.png

Comment: @NarendrakumarM: The images must be in the same place relative to the CSS (not the HTML) that they used to be; paths in CSS files are relative to the CSS file. By default, for instance, jQuery UI expects images to be in an `images` subdirectory, so in your case you'd make sure they were in `css/images/`.

Comment: If I place js & css folder outside WebContent folder. How to call them?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your css file in

```
WebRoot --> Css
```

folder then use below line in your html

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

for example, Your HTml file is in one folder and your CSS/js file is in a folder name "mystyle" inside HTML folder. You should address your CSS file LIKE this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle/style.css" />
```

And if your file is in a folder "before" HTML folder, your address your css/js file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../mystyle/style.css" />
```